# Chose data of last two months in impala

Tags: sql, cloudera, impala

Can somebody help me please and show me how I can incorporate in impala sql my variable: `t2.local_time_createddate` (which is a timestamp variable)?
I would think I need something like this, but cannot get it to work.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE timestamp > DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

That is SQL Server syntax.  I would expect this to work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE timestamp > trunc(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd') - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```